# Highcharts - How can I remove starting and ending padding from area chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vKLPP/

I want to remove the white space on both sides (see the red lines).

[image]

I tried various options like minpadding, margin etc but none of them seem to work.

```
startOnTick: true,
minpadding:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this no need to go with categories or the datetime type of x-axis
just change the data

in this format

data: [,[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],[x5,y5]]

ex:

```
 data: [[1750,106], [1800,107], [1850,111], [1900,133], [1950,221], [1999,767], [2050,1766]]
```

updated your js fiddle please check http://jsfiddle.net/vKLPP/1/

hope this will be useful

Answer (score -1):

According to documentation, minPadding/maxPadding doesn't work with categories. So You should use i.e datetime xAxis and define correct tickInterval / pointInterval.

Comment: Please add a link to the documentation, especially as you're giving instructions to do something, but not even remotely saying how.