# highcharts column chart with line, need line start at bar start

Tags: charts, highcharts, bar-chart, linechart

here is [demo fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/jkwvus8u/5/),

need line chart start from first column left border to last column right border like image below

[image]

in demo fiddel it is start for center of bars.

here is my code of series or you can see in fiddel :

```
series: [{
    name: 'Rainfall',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' mm'
    }

}, {
    name: 'Temperature',
    type: 'line',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    step: 'center',
    rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0
        }
}]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470918/highcharts-how-can-i-remove-starting-and-ending-padding-from-area-chart. Maybe this can help

Comment: Have a look here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086049/how-can-i-force-multiple-y-axis-in-highcharts-to-have-a-common-zero . I am assuming you want the graphs to be aligned at the first and last point.

Comment: Sorry @ewolden  but not working for me

Comment: and @coder not working :(

Comment: Could you try to clarify what exactly you are after, @coder and me have provided suggestion for a solution to two completely different problems.

Comment: @AnkitSoni, check the ans.

Comment: @ewolden maybe thats what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the desired result in two steps:

1. I added a point before the first point and after the last point. Then I set `min` and `max` properties of `xAxis`. This causes that additional points are not visible but lines to them are.
2. Create and apply a clip path to line series. The dimensions of `clipRect` are based on the x positions of the first and the last column:

   ```
   var columnSeries = this.series[0],
     lineSeries = this.series[1],
     firstPoint = columnSeries.points[0],
     lastPoint = columnSeries.points[columnSeries.points.length - 1],
     clipRect = this.renderer.clipRect(firstPoint.shapeArgs.x, 0, lastPoint.plotX, 9999);

   lineSeries.graph.clip(clipRect);
   ```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x2r34huc/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#clip

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some javascript after the highcharts script code. The script is as following:

```
<script>

var rectangles = document.querySelectorAll(".highcharts-series-group > g > rect");
var last = parseInt(rectangles[rectangles.length-1].getAttribute("x")) + parseInt(rectangles[0].getAttribute("x"));
var increment = (last)/11; 
// 11 is the no of gaps in the bar graph
var x=0;

for(i=0;i<rectangles.length;i++)
{
    rectangles[i].setAttribute("x",x);
    x= x+increment;

}
</script>
```

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jkwvus8u/15/

This is probably what you want.But add this code after the highcharts code since it will work on the high chart generated content